# Unable to earn reps through upvotes

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting

Apparently yesterday, someone decided to serially upvote a bunch of my posts. As a result, I gained 196 points, but within an hour they were all reversed. That's all fine, understandable, and even warranted. But since this has occurred, I have not been able to gain reps via upvoting. Even when non-serial-upvoters upvoted my answers, I got no rep!

At first, I thought this was because I hit the ceiling on reps per day, but a) that's not fair because those reps were rolled back, b) I contacted the SO team and they said I shouldn't be capped, 3) I know I'm not capped because I can still earn points via editing and if an answer of mine is accepted.

However, I was unable to earn points via upvotes. I have no idea what's going on and it's very frustrating. I'm essentially being penalized for someone else's actions.

Here is a screen shot of what I'm talking about. Notice I have 19 points there for that day. Then someone upvotes my answer and accepts it, but I only get +15 from it (see subsequent image):

[image]

Notice how I got the +15, but not the rep for the upvotes. What is going on?

[image]

For the record, it happened on stackoverflow.

Comment: Also, I don't think that accepts count towards the repcap.

Answer (score 11):

The system just didn't calculate things properly the first time around when the votes were invalidated. A reputation recalc counted the votes back in as they should be, and your reputation is normal again. It would have fixed this on its own eventually, but an easy way to force the system to rethink things is to just delete and undelete one of your posts, and wait for the recalc system to run again.

Comment: Thanks so much! I see the correction now. I'll keep that in mind for the future!